# Drag and drop file upload & should also drag up and down of file uploads in Angular 4

Tags: angular, npm, drag-and-drop

I want to create drag and drop feature. Uploads should be listed down. It must have feature of drag up and down in that list only. Is there any npm package for that?
If yes please let me know. Or if it isn't available then tell me briefly how to do that and is it possible in Angular 4.2v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ngx-file-drop

1. An Angular 8 module for simple desktop file and folder drag and drop. This library does not need rxjs-compat.
2. For Angular 7, 6, 5 and 4 support please use older versions.
3. This library relies on HTML 5 File API thus IE and Safari are not supported

Click [here for the demo](https://georgipeltekov.github.io/).

- They have template code which indeed will help you alot.